Nav menu sometimes cannot be closed in MudBlazor
I'm learning and trying to use MudBlazor to develop my website. But when I add my custom page (still using the page paths of the pages in MudTemplate), the Navigation Menu cannot be closed. On some sites, it may be closed. When I try to debug the function that sets the value for the parameter that determines the opening and closing of the navigation menu as DrawerToggle, on some pages it works, on some pages it doesn't. I spent all day trying to find the answer but to no avail. What should I do?
Here is my MainLayout:
@using MUDTEMPLATE.Components
@using MUDTEMPLATE.DBData
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IConfiguration config

<MudThemeProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<MudDialogProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<MudSnackbarProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="0">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" Target="_blank" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" Elevation="1" Variant="DrawerVariant.Temporary">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">DATAVIET - MART</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraExtraLarge" Class="my-1 pt-1">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        DB.Set_Connect(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}

Here is my NavMenu:
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<MudNavMenu>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <MudNavGroup Title="System" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard" Expanded="true">
                <MudNavLink Href="/Account/Register" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.PeopleAlt">Register</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="counter" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.List">Counter</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="weather" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.List">Weather</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="Account/Manage" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.List">@context.User.Identity?.Name</MudNavLink>
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
                    <AntiforgeryToken />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="" />
                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link">
                        <span class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            @* <MudNavLink Href="Account/Register" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.List">Register</MudNavLink> *@
            <MudNavLink Href="Account/Login" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.List">Login</MudNavLink>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</MudNavMenu>
@code {
    private string? currentUrl;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }

    private void OnLocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(e.Location);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
    }
}

Here is my Counter page (Nav Menu working here):
@page "/counter"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Counter</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-4">Current count: @currentCount</MudText>
<MudButton Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</MudButton>
    @code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

Here is my Register page (Nav Menu not working):
@page "/Account/Register"

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Text
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@using MUDTEMPLATE.Data

@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@inject IUserStore<ApplicationUser> UserStore
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject IEmailSender<ApplicationUser> EmailSender
@inject ILogger<Register> Logger
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager

<PageTitle>Register</PageTitle>

<h1>Register</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <StatusMessage Message="@Message" />
        <EditForm Model="Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="RegisterUser" FormName="register">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to register.</h3>
            <hr />
            <ExternalLoginPicker />
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<IdentityError>? identityErrors;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    private string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    private string? Message => identityErrors is null ? null : $"Error: {string.Join(", ", identityErrors.Select(error => error.Description))}";

    public async Task RegisterUser(EditContext editContext)
    {
        var user = CreateUser();

        await UserStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var emailStore = GetEmailStore();
        await emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            identityErrors = result.Errors;
            return;
        }

        Logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

        var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var callbackUrl = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
            NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Account/ConfirmEmail").AbsoluteUri,
            new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = userId, ["code"] = code, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });

        await EmailSender.SendConfirmationLinkAsync(user, Input.Email, HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));

        if (UserManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
        {
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
                "Account/RegisterConfirmation",
                new() { ["email"] = Input.Email, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });
        }

        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
    }

    private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
    {
        try
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}'. " +
                $"Ensure that '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor.");
        }
    }

    private IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> GetEmailStore()
    {
        if (!UserManager.SupportsUserEmail)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
        }
        return (IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>)UserStore;
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } = "";
    }
}



The /Account/xxx pages are Static Server Side Rendered pages. The important part being static. Once a static page is rendered, c# methods on that page are no longer executed and interactivity is no longer available.
This is standard Blazor behavior and interactive components will not work on these pages without additional javascript.

I just started learning about Blazor and Mud not too long ago so the question seems a bit silly but the point is that I used the pre-made page when creating the Mudblazor template, edited its content and now it becomes static page? Can you show me how to fix it? Because even my login page has the problem of not being able to interact with the Nav Menu even though it can perform the normal login function which I consider dynamic.

As I stated before this is standard Blazor behaviour for the Account pages. Login is also an account page. Forms are the only components that work on static pages. None of this is related to MudBlazor and there nothing to be fixed, it behaves as expected.

I discovered that all the components where the Nav Menu doesn't work are in a place where the pages use a separate layout inherited from the MainLayout. My question is why does it inherit the Nav Menu in Main Layout but the open and close method does not?

Because the pages are statically rendered. All account pages are static. You are free to remove the menu from those pages if you so choose

Sorry for my dumb question. But I see that with MudBlazor's existing Template that I'm using. When logging in, a Nav Menu component will appear, which will take the user to the account information management page if clicked on it. Is it normal for users to get there and find themselves stuck there because they can't open the Navigation Menu and navigate to other pages? Or is there any other workaround for such problems?


I don't use the templates so I'm not really sure what you're referring to.
I could only assume you are talking about a screen size where the menu auto-hides... can't you just use the back button?
The template is just a basic example based off of Microsoft templates... if something isn't to your liking just change it.


This is a major flaw in Blazor layouts.  When on a ssr rendered page there is no interactivity, ether go global with interactivity (its own set of problems as you cannot set interactivity mode, or wait until someone finds a solution. It really SUCKS!

Not sure what you mean by wait until someone finds a solution. Simply use javascript if you need interactivity on static pages.
